# 2.0 Web Service Proxy to WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a 2.0 Web Service proxy generated for a WCF Service.  This service required Basic authentication, but periodically we experience problems that the proxy cannot connect to the Server.

The application is installed on a cluster and referencing a cluster that holds the WCF Service.

Anyone experience this problem already?

Comment: Please provide more details about this part: "periodically we experience problems that the proxy cannot connect to the Server."

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the service is only installed / working on one server in the cluster. Therefore, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not, depending on which machine you hit.

Comment: We had already verified this prior to posting this (took one of our WCF servers offline) but the issues remain.

Something I would like to mention as well is that the client is a 3.5 app (so they should have used the WCF proxy, which was my answer and fixed there problem), but we also have to support some 2.0 apps which do not have this solution!

Comment: @Patrick for the 2.0 apps you could expose the functionality and asmx web services. Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly it has to do with the setup of the environment.  All the machines are virtual and the errors occurs depending on the host they are running on.  I also was able to reproduce it with the WCF Proxy as well by switching on/off VM's.

thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider deploying an ASMX service backed by the WCF service class. This gives you a classic XML webservices facade to work with.